# is a good approach using public methods in dto?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, dto

I'm learning Nestjs and now I'm coding a simple API to manage customers, I made an endpoint to create a new customer and I have a class dto to check fields and some validations before inserting a new one. Is add some methods inside to class dto a good practice?

```
export class CreateCustomerDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;
.
. More
. Fields
. Here
.
  public setLowercaseName() {
    return this.name.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Yes, I know I can add some decorator or transform to do the same thing, but It's just an example of what I would like to do but I don't know if it is a good practice working with class methods in dto...

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe encapsulate it in a separate supporter/helper class, DTOs are supposed to be just small data objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DTOs are simple objects that should not contain any business logic but may contain serialization and deserialization mechanisms for transferring data over the wire.`

In my opinion you can have public methods to do some operations on its data but make sure that the method is implementing a very specific operation **related to only DTO** and not something like `this.name.toLowerCase();` because that is something common and should be defined as a helper.

Comment: so Do you think is a better approach to create utils file for example to add these business functions? Your answer is very very complete but now I'm thinking in how I should organize my code in terms of functions

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, it is better to take it to the transformer and apply it here

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).